# How to format HTTP headers for using paypal in php?

Tags: php, paypal

I'm trying to implement the paypal [pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/gs_AdaptivePayments/). i can understand the 1st point but the second point is confusing, which says load HTTP headers with the information like

```
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID : Sandbox-Caller-User-Id
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD : Sandbox-Caller-Password
X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE : Sandbox-Caller-Security-Signature 
etc
```

Am not sure how to give these information.Should it be given through form or something else?  I would like to do it in php.which format should  i use to send this information?

can anyone show me some simple sample to go to `step 5` Figure 2. Authorizing the Payment.
i tried this below form which is from the paypal site example itself

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay"
target="PPDGFrame">
<input id="type" type="hidden" name="expType" value="light">
<input id="paykey" type="hidden" name="paykey" value="AP-...">
<input id="preapprovalkey" type="hidden" name="preapprovalkey" value="PA-...">
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Pay with PayPal">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [curl](http://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php) for PHP. In curl you can set headers like this:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.paypal.com/webapps/adaptivepayment/flow/pay');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Set the headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: yourvalue',
 'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: yourvalue'
));

$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close($ch);

/* EOF */
```

Send your form to this PHP script and extend it that it fits the needs of the paypal API.

Comment: Thanks i tried.But `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()`

Comment: Check your phpinfo() if the curl extension is installed and enabled. If not install the extension, enable it in your php.ini and restart / reload configuration of your webserver

Comment: I tried some e-commerce plugin which use paypal in local server but those are working fine.

Comment: Which plugin for which ecommerce software?

Comment: easy digital download for wordpress

Comment: Okay, don't know how this plugin works exactly. But I recommend you, that you install and use curl to communicate with the API of paypal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40196/discussion-between-sun-and-timesplinter)